# Unable to copy a file from remote server to local machine

Tags: linux, scp

I'm trying to copy a file to my local machine. While in the terminal of the remote server:

```
scp root@servername:filename.json ~/Desktop/
```

This returns:

> /root/Desktop/: No such file or directory

So then I tried:

```
scp root@servername:filename.json ~/
```

which returned:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> ssh: connect to host 02 port 22: Invalid argument

Any idea what I can do to make this work? I am logged in as root user.

Comment: `Permission denied (publickey).` - use the correct key.

Comment: Should `~/Desktop/` refer to your local machine? Then you should run the first command on your local machine instead of "in the terminal of the remote server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scp` command copies from its first argument(s) to its last. If you run `scp root@servername:filename.json ~/Desktop/` in the remote terminal, you're telling `scp` to connect to *the same server that you are already using* and copy a file from there to the local destination directory `~/Desktop/`. Remember that *local* in this instance is the machine on which you're running `scp`, i.e. the remote server, so it's roughly equivalent to `cp ~root/filename.json ~/Desktop`.

To copy a file to your local machine run it locally. Or if your local machine is accessible from the remote, invert the arguments and run it in the context of the remote server:

```
scp ~root/filename.json myUser@myLocal:Desktop/    # Might need sudo to read ~root files
```